# Symfony console error

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony project. Whenever I run the build command using doctrine keyword I am getting the following error.

```
Task "doctrine" is ambiguous (doctrine:create-db, doctrine:clean).
```

Please do tell me, what I am getting this error and how can it be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you must executing

```
$ app/console doctrine
```

which causes this error. You have to explicitly run task(s), eg.

```
$ app/console doctrine:create-db
$ app/console doctrine:clean
```